# Setting CAPS_LOCK + arrows to Home, PgUp, PgDown, End in xkb

Tags: kde, xkb, setxkbmap

I'm trying to set some <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> + arrows keybindings in `xkb`

Using ArchLinux, KDE, Xorg

### What I'm trying to achieve (wishful thinking)

Ultimately, the perfect solution would be

| No modifier | <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> as modifier |
| --- | --- |
| <kbd>Left</kbd> | <kbd>Home</kbd> |
| <kbd>Up</kbd> | <kbd>PageUp</kbd> |
| <kbd>Right</kbd> | <kbd>End</kbd> |
| <kbd>Down</kbd> | <kbd>PageDown</kbd> |

while pressing just <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> would work on key release, as normal latching <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>.

Adding <kbd>Shift</kbd> into the mix, or any keybind that uses mapped keys for that matter, should still work.

Moreover, for better compatibility, these bindings should work on keysym level and not using (state, key).

### The problem

I don't believe this does what I'd like it to do, and probably doesn't even parse

`capslock_nav` (added to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`)

```
xkb_symbols "lv3-arrow-nav" {
    include "level3(caps_switch)"
    key.type = "THREE_LEVEL";
    key   <UP> {         [              Up, Up, Prior, NoSymbol] };
    key <LEFT> {         [            Left, Left, Home, NoSymbol ] };
    key <RGHT> {         [           Right, Right, End, NoSymbol ] };
    key <DOWN> {         [            Down, Down, Next, NoSymbol ] };
}
```

and I've been trying to achieve this by setting <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to `ISO_Level3_Shift` and using that in `symbols` declarations, but to no avail.

### Progress so far

My changes are visible in KDE's `Settings > Keyboard > Advanced` list, that was accomplished by adding entry to
`evdev.xml`, like so

```xml
<!-- ... under <optionList> ... -->
<group allowMultipleSelection="true">
      <configItem>
        <name>capslock_nav</name>
        <description>Navigation using CapsLock</description>
      </configItem>
      <option>
        <configItem>
          <name>capslock_nav:lv3-arrow-nav</name>
          <description>Caps Lock Arrow Navigation</description>
        </configItem>
      </option>
    </group>
```

and this one to `evdev.lst`, just to be sure

```
...
  capslock_nav         Navigation using CapsLock
  capslock_nav:lv3-arrow-nav Caps Lock Arrow Navigation
...
```

this is also somewhat reflected by `setxkbmap`:

```bsh
setxkbmap -print -query
xkb_keymap {
        xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
        xkb_types     { include "complete"      };
        xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
        xkb_symbols   { include "pc+pl+inet(evdev)"     };
        xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc86)"      };
};
rules:      evdev
model:      pc86
layout:     pl
options:    capslock_nav:lv3-arrow-nav
```

`options` contain my changes, but it's not included in `xkb_symbols`.
`xkbcomp $DISPLAY -` also has no mention of my changes.

I've gone through ArchWiki and various articles online on the topic, but it's a bit complicated. I feel like I'm making some progress, it's just that it's very slow.

#### EDIT: Progress so far

I've dropped my configs and started working off of
[xkb#caps hjkl on archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/X_keyboard_extension#Caps_hjkl_as_vimlike_arrow_keys)

and prepared this config, which I've split into corresponding files
(`compat`, `symbols` `types`)

```
partial xkb_types "lv3-arrow-nav" {
    include "complete";
    type "CUST_CAPSLOCK" {
       modifiers= Shift+Lock; 
       map[Shift] = Level2;            //maps shift and no Lock. Shift+Alt goes here, too, because Alt isn't in modifiers.
       map[Lock] = Level3;
       map[Shift+Lock] = Level3;       //maps shift and Lock. Shift+Lock+Alt goes here, too.
       level_name[Level1]= "Base";
       level_name[Level2]= "Shift";
       level_name[Level3]= "Lock";
   };
}

partial xkb_compatibility "lv3-arrow-nav" {
    interpret Caps_Lock {
        action= SetMods(modifiers=Lock);
    };
    augment "complete";
    augment "caps(caps_lock)";
}

partial xkb_symbols "lv3-arrow-nav" {
    include "pc";
    key <LEFT> {
       type= "CUST_CAPSLOCK",
       symbols[Group1]= [               Left,               Left,               Home],
       actions[Group1]= [      NoAction(),      NoAction(),   RedirectKey(keycode=<LEFT>, clearmods=Lock) ]
    };
    key <UP> {
        type= "CUST_CAPSLOCK",
        symbols[Group1]= [               Up,               Up,               Prior],
        actions[Group1]= [      NoAction(),      NoAction(),   RedirectKey(keycode=<UP>, clearmods=Lock) ]
    };
    key <RGHT> {
        type= "CUST_CAPSLOCK",
        symbols[Group1]= [               Right,               Right,               End],
        actions[Group1]= [      NoAction(),      NoAction(),   RedirectKey(keycode=<RGHT>, clearmods=Lock) ]
    };
    key <DOWN> {
        type= "CUST_CAPSLOCK",
        symbols[Group1]= [               Down,               Down,               Next],
        actions[Group1]= [      NoAction(),      NoAction(),   RedirectKey(keycode=<DOWN>, clearmods=Lock) ]
    };
}
```

which I've validated using `xkbcomp`, but it still does not behave in expected way.

#### EDIT2

Well, at least it does *something*, because this config,

```
xkb
├── compat
│  └── capslock_nav
├── rules
│  └── evdev
├── symbols
│  └── capslock_nav
├── types
│  └── capslock_nav
└── xkb_keymap.xkb
```

applied using

```bsh
xkbcomp -I$HOME/xkb/ $HOME/xkb/xkb_keymap.xkb $DISPLAY
```

at least disables caps lock...

#### EDIT3

Looks like I've made some progress, by making all actions = `NoAction()` in `symbols` definition

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is as far as I'm getting:

#### Working

- <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Right</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd> working as <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>PageUp</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>PageDown</kbd>
- existing layout settings preserved (I can still use `pl` layout, set in KDE's keyboard settings)

#### Not working

- integration with KDE's `keyboard > advanced` toggles - toggle is there, but it only changes `symbols` includes when queried by `setxkbmap -query`
- stand-alone <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> as usual <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> latch

### The solution

I've created a folder structure compliant with xkeyboard-config, like so
(the xkb/**/* part)

```
$HOME/xkb_mod
├── xkb
│  ├── compat
│  │  └── capslock_nav
│  ├── symbols
│  │  └── capslock_nav
│  └── types
│     └── capslock_nav
└── xkb_keymap.xkb
```

`xkb/` will be part of `-I` includes

##### File contents

(inspired by https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/X_keyboard_extension#Caps_hjkl_as_vimlike_arrow_keys )

`compat/capslock_nav`

```
partial xkb_compatibility "caps-arrow-nav" {
    interpret Caps_Lock {
        action= SetMods(modifiers=Lock);
    };
};
```

`symbols/capslock_nav`

```
partial xkb_symbols "caps-arrow-nav" {
    key <LEFT> {
       type= "CUST_CAPSLOCK",
       symbols[Group1]= [               Left,               Left,               Home]
    };
    key <UP> {
        type= "CUST_CAPSLOCK",
        symbols[Group1]= [               Up,               Up,               Prior]
    };
    key <RGHT> {
        type= "CUST_CAPSLOCK",
        symbols[Group1]= [               Right,               Right,               End]
    };
    key <DOWN> {
        type= "CUST_CAPSLOCK",
        symbols[Group1]= [               Down,               Down,               Next]
    };
};
```

`types/capslock_nav`

```
partial xkb_types "caps-arrow-nav" {
    type "CUST_CAPSLOCK" {
       modifiers= Shift+Lock; 
       map[Shift] = Level2;            //maps shift and no Lock. Shift+Alt goes here, too, because Alt isn't in modifiers.
       map[Lock] = Level3;
       map[Shift+Lock] = Level3;       //maps shift and Lock. Shift+Lock+Alt goes here, too.
       level_name[Level1]= "Base";
       level_name[Level2]= "Shift";
       level_name[Level3]= "Lock";
   };
};
```

After that I've queried existing settings and put them in `xkb_keymap.xkb`

```bsh
setxkbmap -query > ~/xkb_mod/xkb_keymap.xkb
```

and manually included `+capslock_nav(caps-arrow-nav)` in every `include`,
like so:

`xkb_keymap.xkb`

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete+capslock_nav(caps-arrow-nav)" };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete+capslock_nav(caps-arrow-nav)" };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+pl+inet(evdev)+capslock_nav(caps-arrow-nav)"    };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc86)"  };
};
```

Finally, I've applied the config by running

```bsh
xkbcomp -I$HOME/xkb_mod/xkb xkb_mod/xkb_keymap.xkb $DISPLAY
```